# How to plot a multiple columns for one row using R

Tags: r

I have a data set aus_noscl contains 1 row and multiple columns, for example :

```
Country      x1999      x2000      x2001      x2002
Australia    27,5444    26,200     27,243     15,685
```

I want to plot a histogram to compare years,

I have tried :

```
  barplot(cbind(aus_noscl$X2010, aus_noscl$X2011, aus_noscl$X2012,
          aus_noscl$X2013))
```

But:
It will take a long time writing all columns names and in the graph no name for columns appear, so it's not valuable visualization.

Would be very grateful for easy and effective idea for this kind of data, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `unlist` the dataset excluding the first column, remove the `,` using `gsub`, convert to `numeric` class, set the names of the `vector` by the column names and then do the `barplot`.

```
barplot(setNames(as.numeric(gsub(',', '', 
          unlist(aus_nosci[-1]))), names(aus_nosci[-1])))
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun , this is exactly what i needed, appreciate